# How to add default value for a dependency property in UWP from static resource

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am writing a custom Hyperlink control(by inheriting from Hyperlink), In my custom style I have multiple textblocks and i want to allow users using my custom control to be able to assign style to these textblocks themselves and apply the static resource style in my resources only when nothing is defined b the user.

MyHyerlink.cs

```
public partial class MyHyperlink : HyperlinkButton
{
    public MyHyperlink()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyHyperlink);
    }

    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        _txtTitle = GetTemplateChild(TextTitle) as TextBlock;
        _txtContent = GetTemplateChild(TextContent) as TextBlock;
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleStyleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(TitleStyle),
        typeof(Style),
        typeof(MyHyperlink),
        new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public Style TitleStyle
    {
        get { return (Style)GetValue(TitleStyleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TitleStyleProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DescriptionStyleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(DescriptionStyle),
        typeof(Style),
        typeof(MyHyperlink),
        new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public Style DescriptionStyle
    {
        get { return (Style)GetValue(DescriptionStyleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DescriptionStyleProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

MyHyperlink.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Myproject.Controls">
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="UrlTitleStyle">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
</Style>
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="UrlDescriptionStyle">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="9" />
</Style>
<Style TargetType="local:MyHyperlink">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyHyperlink">
                <Grid>
                    <!--Url Part template with parsed image and http content-->
                    <Border Name="UrlPartTemplate">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Image VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                   Name="imgLogo"
                                   Grid.Column="0"
                                   />
                            <TextBlock Name="txtTitle"
                                       Grid.Column="1"
                                       Margin="5 0"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                       MaxLines="2"
                                       Style="{StaticResource UrlTitleStyle}"
                                       TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                            <TextBlock Name="txtContent"
                                       Grid.Row="1"
                                       Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                       Margin="5, 5"
                                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                       MaxLines="3"
                                       Style="{StaticResource UrlDescriptionStyle}"
                                       TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

So In the above xaml, controls txtContent and txtTitle should take the style from static resource only when nothing is provided to the TitleStyle and DescriptionStyle dependency props declared in the code.

Can anyone help me out with this, Thanks

Comment: Did you try this `public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleStyleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
       nameof(TitleStyle),
       typeof(Style),
       typeof(OpacityMask),
       new PropertyMetadata(Application.Current.Resources["UrlDescriptionStyle"]));`

Comment: Yes i did...problem is the control am creating is in a separate project(class library) altogether with the app..So the static resource i defined would not exist in the App resources, I need to define my default style in the class library itself for which i have tried to define those in the same resource dictionary where the control template is derived from but it doesnt seem to find that.

Comment: Try giving value inside control's style? Like`<Setter Property="DescriptionStyle" Value="{StaticResource UrlDescriptionStyle}"/>`

Comment: Not sure how this would work...i need to apply this particular style to one of the control defined inside the custom control...and moreover it would become hardcoded right? It wouldnt be able to apply any style assigned to dependency property from Application xaml

Comment: You can change its value later in xaml.  How would it become hardcoded? Its a default value. If you dont assign any value this value will be taken.

Comment: hmm it works actually....I thought the templatebinding applied to the control  would take null always from the default value of the dep property... Anyway thanks for the help....

Comment: OH Great. I ll write it as answer then. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give default value for property in control's style itself like this.

```
<Style TargetType="local:MyHyperlink">
<Setter Property="DescriptionStyle" Value="{StaticResource UrlDescriptionStyle}"/>
...
</Style>
```